# Screen Reader turns on mistakenly

Tags: accessibility

Since the last update whatever I do anything on my system a sound erupts like if i change the brightness using <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> keys or change volume or open any drive or folder or any file a voice repeats the whole process like on pressing down volume<kbd>F8</kbd> key a voice  **volume  19 erupts** from  speaker or I open any folder sound erupts that "new folder" is open.do anybody has idea what is happening on key press or opening any file or folder why this sound is coming whatever I do on my system. whatever I browse on Firefox any site anything I type it is repeated I am typing this question and it is being read out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer I've used key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.This has cause Screen reader to turn on  .I've to turn it off by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again as it was not Turn on visually in **System Settings-->Universal Access-->Seeing-->Screen reader**

[image: Screen Reader]

Comment: That's odd, It shows as on if I toggle it the way you did. then I have to turn it off via the System Settings-->Universal Access-->Seeing-->Screen reader. I wonder why your results are different?

Comment: @ElderGeek ya it happens only once I'm unable to recreate that situation agian